# Pgfplots bar chart with \times symbol as multiplier

Tags: pgfplots

I have a bar chart with relatively large values and I am using the near `coords` option to show the values over the bars. I want the `\times` symbol instead of `\cdot` for `pgfplots` multiplier. I know how to change it for axis by `/pgfplots/tick scale binop=\times` but I am not sure if it is possible to do the same thing for the values shown over the bars.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[/pgfplots/tick scale binop=\times,
title=128-bit,
ybar,
height=4.5in,
width=3.3in,
ymin=0,
legend style={at={(0.3,0.95)},anchor=north},
enlarge y limits={upper,value=0.5},
enlarge x limits=0.15,
height=2.5in,
bar width = 7pt,
major tick length=0cm,
nodes near coords,
symbolic x  coords={1NN,10NN,100NN},
xtick=data,
every node near coord/.append style={rotate=90, anchor=west},
]   
\addplot coordinates {(1NN,38751) (10NN,84295) (100NN,162122)};
\addplot coordinates {(1NN,17040) (10NN,55571) (100NN,175327)};
\addplot coordinates {(1NN,55791) (10NN,139866) (100NN,337449)};
\legend{$\#$ comp,$\#$ buck, Total}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crude quick hack:

```
\def\cdot{\times}
```

Or without disabling `\cdot`:
I have not found a configuration option. `\cdot` is hardcoded in the internal macro `\pgfmathfloatrounddisplaystyle@std`, which is assigned to `\pgfmathfloatrounddisplaystyle`. The following example file redefines these macros to use `\times` instead of `\cdot`. Also the `y limit` is enlarged a bit, because the numbers now need more space.

\documentclass[10pt]{article}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}

```
\makeatletter
\def\pgfmathfloatrounddisplaystyle@std#1#2e#3\relax{%
  \pgfmathfloatrounddisplaystyle@shared@impl#1#2e#3\relax{\times}{}{10^{#3}}%
}
\let\pgfmathfloatrounddisplaystyle\pgfmathfloatrounddisplaystyle@std
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  /pgfplots/tick scale binop=\times,
  title=128-bit,
  ybar,
  height=4.5in,
  width=3.3in,
  ymin=0,
  legend style={at={(0.3,0.95)},anchor=north},
  enlarge y limits={upper,value=0.6},
  enlarge x limits=0.15,
  height=2.5in,
  bar width = 7pt,
  major tick length=0cm,
  nodes near coords,
  symbolic x  coords={1NN,10NN,100NN},
  xtick=data,
  every node near coord/.append style={rotate=90, anchor=west},
]
  \addplot coordinates {(1NN,38751) (10NN,84295) (100NN,162122)};
  \addplot coordinates {(1NN,17040) (10NN,55571) (100NN,175327)};
  \addplot coordinates {(1NN,55791) (10NN,139866) (100NN,337449)};
  \legend{$\#$ comp,$\#$ buck, Total}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]